# How to do a SQL Query that will combine strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation

I have a MSSQL database table with data like:

```
----------------------------------------
| Id | PartNo | Price  | Qty| ExtPrice |
----------------------------------------
| 1  | Thing1  | 1.50  |  2 |  3.00    |
----------------------------------------
| 2  | Thing 2 | 2.50  |  3 | 7.50     |
----------------------------------------
```

The last three fields I can do a SUM() with my GROUP BY, But I need it to combine the PartNo Field like this:

```
--------------------------------------------
| PartNo          | Price | Qty | ExtPrice |
--------------------------------------------
| Thing1, Thing2  | 4.00  |  5  |  10.50   |
--------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using any version older than SQL Server 2017 `STRING_AGG()` will not be available for you to use, for older version you can use the `FOR XML PATH('')` method to concatenate the strings, something like this...

```
SELECT STUFF((  SELECT ',' + PartNo
                FROM TableName 
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
                .value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1 ,1,'') AS PartNo
      , SUM(Price)      AS Price
      , SUM(Qty)        AS Qty
      , SUM(ExtPrice)   AS ExtPrice
FROM TableName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [STRING_AGG (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) aggregate function.

```
SELECT 
    STRING_AGG (PartNo, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PartNo ASC) AS PartNo,
    SUM(Price) As Price, 
    SUM(Qty) As Qty, 
    SUM(ExtPrice) As ExtPrice
FROM MyTable;
```

See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/77ff1/2/0

Btw.: There is no more column left to group by, so, you can just drop the GROUP BY.